# Filter non-IP traffic on STA wlan0 interface

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, bridge, wlan, nftables

I want to filter inbound and outbound non-IP traffic going through the wlan0 interface of a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (connected via Wi-Fi to an AP).

- iptables / ip6tables only seem to affect IP traffic, so cannot be used for other ethertypes.
- ebtables supports non-IP ethertypes, but only works on bridge interfaces. Bridging a Wi-Fi STA interface seems to require 4addr mode, but that one does not seem to be supported by Raspberry Pi 3B+.
- nftables supports the netdev family with an ingress hook, but this only works for inbound traffic.

Is there a way to filter all non-IP traffic passing in and out of my Raspberry Pi? I would like to drop most packets (beside a limited allowlist), and would also like to log certain inbound packets (e.g., libnetfilter_log).

Comment: I'd know how to drop, but not how to log. Even handling a whitelist would require you already gave a *precise* example of such whitelist.

Comment: How would a drop look? That info alone may be useful. At least with ebtables you can send packets to nflog while dropping them, but ebtables is not available on wlan0 afaik.

Comment: If your drop method happens after the packet went through pcap, maybe libpcap could be used for the logging part.